# Do we still need to disable request validation when using Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

In ASP.NET MVC views, it is typical to bind model values using Razor's syntax:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)
```

We know that Razor will html encode the value by default. But imagine a malicious user inputting scripts in a textbox and submitting it:

```
<script>alert('Executing evil script')</script>
```

Now if we do not use the `[ValidateInput(false)]` or `[AllowHtml]` attributes, we will be hit with a `HttpRequestValidationException` which means this exception have to be caught every time a user submits a form.

From the answer in another stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client), I know we can disable request validation on an application level but many are suggesting this is a bad practice.

My question is, given we have Razor to escape all `&gt;` and `&lt;`, can we assume the site will still be secure if we turn off request validation?

Comment: Given there is `Html.Raw` I'm not sure how Razor is important part of the decision to use or not request validation... It was never required, but useful if you don't expect "evil script" as inputs.

Answer (score 0):

No, relying only HTML encoding during Razor page generation and switching off request validation is not a good strategy to combat XSS attacks:

- Request Validation prevents bad user input from getting into your database / storage / other user screens in the first place.
- Html encoding (sanitization) is there as a backup strategy, e.g. where the attacker has already got through the door.
- Considering that an App can serve more than just Html - e.g. Xml and REST services, which will not be subject to the encoding by the Html helpers. (e.g. attacker might find a way to put a malicious payload in an Xml CDATA section)
- Also, consider running regular Sql / NoSql queries against your database looking for signs that your site request validation has been compromised.

Comment: Then how can I allow users to enter `&lt;` and `&gt;` in textboxes safely without the application crashing with a `HttpRequestValidationException`?

Comment: You allow just that one field for Html, use a mainstream Html editor like *CKEditor or TinyMCE etc, and [configure](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:valid_elements) your Html editor control just to allow specific Html tags. No scripts. And not all Html, otherwise an attacker can still deface your site.

Comment: @StuartLC: Configuring a *client side editor* does nothing to protect your server from malicious HTML. You need to validate everything on the server side. And that's very difficult to do correctly.